# Merge every 2 consecutive records into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a pre-processed table which I want to group every pair into one record containing data from fields of both records.

```
|-------------------|-----|----|
|Timestamp          |Event|User|
|-------------------|-----|----|
|17/03/2020 03:22:00|Start|1   |
|17/03/2020 03:22:05|End  |1   |
|17/03/2020 03:22:10|Start|2   |
|17/03/2020 03:22:15|End  |2   |
|17/03/2020 03:23:00|Start|1   |
|17/03/2020 03:23:22|End  |1   |
|-------------------|-----|----|
```

The query should return:

```
|-------------------|-------------------|----|
|StartTimestamp     |EndTimestamp       |User|
|-------------------|-------------------|----|
|17/03/2020 03:22:00|17/03/2020 03:22:05|1   |
|17/03/2020 03:22:10|17/03/2020 03:22:15|2   |
|17/03/2020 03:23:00|17/03/2020 03:23:22|1   |
|-------------------|-------------------|----|
```

You can safely assume that every 2 records is the correct pair *(events are Start and End respectively, and User is the same)* since the table is pre-filtered.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to mention that having multiple pairs for a single user is allowed. I've adjusted the example table above to show that.

Comment: use `GROUP BY [User]` and aggregate `MIN()` and `MAX()` on the `Timestamp`

Comment: Can multiple events per user occur? Your sample data makes it look like there is just one event (one start, one end) per user, but is this really the case?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry about that, having multiple pairs per user is possible. I just edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Can parallel events occur, e.g. user 1 starts an event, then user 2 starts an event, then user 1 ends their event, then user 2 ends their event? Your sample data makes it look like there is always one user at a time first starting then ending, before another user can start. Is this really the case?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, records can be inserted in parallel. However, that constraint was waived when I said that the table was pre-filtered/processed (see last paragraph before edit). I already have a query that transforms it into that pair format.

The question literally then becomes just how to merge every 2 records into 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, this should do what you want :

```
SELECT
     MIN(Timestamp) AS StartTimestamp,
     MAX(Timestamp) AS EndTimestamp,
     User
FROM 
     mytable
GROUP BY User;
```

EDIT : As a user id can appear multiple times, in multiple groups, see the following query :

```
WITH cte AS (
     SELECT mt.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY time) AS rn FROM mytable mt
)
SELECT 
     t1.userid,
     t1.time AS StartTimestamp, 
     t2.time AS EndTimestamp
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 ON t1.rn+1 = t2.rn
WHERE t1.event = 'Start'
```

[**WITH DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b60497e9495b2fab1ba4ad65fdad1a9b)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that having multiple pairs for a single user is possible. I'll update the question.

Comment: Neat, just exactly what I need; also clever usage of the row number.

Comment: @JohnMarkGabrielCaguicla . . . I wouldn't recommend either solution for your problem.  The second is quite inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` & do conditional aggregation  :

```
select user, 
       min(case when event = 'Start' then timestamp end) as starttimestamp,
       min(case when event = 'End' then timestamp end) as endtimestamp
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by user, event order by timestamp) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by user, seq;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `lead()` or a cumulative `min()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when event = 'End' then timestamp end) over (partition by user order by timestamp desc) as end_time
      from t
     ) t
where event = 'Start';
```

Answer (score 0):

Number the rows per user and event to get to event numbers. Then join event starts with event ends.

```
with s as
(
  select
    [user], timestamp,
    row_number() over (partition by [user] order by timestamp) as event_number
  from mytable
  where event = 'Start'
)
, e as
(
  select
    [user], timestamp,
    row_number() over (partition by [user] order by timestamp) as event_number
  from mytable
  where event = 'End'
)
select s.[user], s.timestamp as start_time, e.timestamp as end_time
from s
join e on e.[user] = s.[user] and e.event_number = s.event_number
order by start_time;
```

Use a left outer join, if you want to show events that have started but not ended yet.

This query also allows for parallel events (i.e. a user starts an event, then another user starts an event before the first user ends theirs).

What the query doesn't account for are missing events, e.g. a user starts an event, but when they end it, it's not recorded in the table. Then the user starts a new event and end it and my query will relate the second event's end with the first event's start.